# page based navigation using workflow

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation

I want to develop and WPF navigation application using work flow. can oany one provide me with a list of tutorials on it

Comment: Navigation is easy (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx and http://alski.net/post/2012/01/11/WPF-Wizards.aspx), but I'm not sure what you mean by based on workflow. Can you explain more?

Comment: basically i want to develop a WPF navigation application. In which The workflow will determine which page to be navigated. how can i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can elaborate a little on your requirements, I'm sure you'll get some better answers.

Here's a pretty straight forward tutorial on creating Navigation Based Applications in WPF

www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kaps_deo/create-navigation-based-application-in-wpf/

As for WF, personally, I prefer the tutorials and articles on msdn, here are a few links that should get you started:

General overview and a good place to start:

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735967(v=vs.90)

Some interesting video tutorials:

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff802403.aspx

here is also an article about hosting WF in your own application:

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663362.aspx

As for how the both interact, here are some links that I found through a quick google search:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Windows-Workflow-eaa24bdb
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42505/Methods-of-WPF-WF-Data-Exchange-Direct-WPF-WF-Data

Hope this was helpful,

Max

P.S. I'm sorry, I can't post more than 2 hyperlinks, because I'm new to posting here.

Comment: basically i want to develop a WPF navigation application. In which The workflow will determine which page to be navigated. how can i implement this?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.

I think that just hosting the WF in the application, and having your navigation controls check the state of the workflow when they're pressed, can do that trick just fine.

For example: You have a state workflow, and then you just check the state, when your button is clicked, to decide which page to navigate to.

I hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use start by reading up on Navigation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx and MVVM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx and starting with a simple frame demonstration style application. Make sure you are navigating to the viewmodels and letting the Frame display the correct view by specifying DataTemplates with DataType="{x:Type...}".

The navigation frame gives you controls to go back, but not forwards (at least not until you've been to them once), so you will need to decide how your view shows controls for these (e.g. a single next button only, or multiple links on a page where a branch decision is made). Lets take the case of the multiple links since its the most complex, when you create the viewmodel you need to interrogated WF for its links to nodes following the current node, and create ViewModel commands that map to those nodes. This gives you an iterative process (over the lifetime of the entire navigation) to navigate one path through the tree.